# Anonymize data in column 1 and column 3 of tables in an HTML file

Tags: python, perl, sed

I have an HTML file with several tables in it. I would like to change the data in columns 1 and columns 3 to name+number, where number increments after each row updated. So this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">                              
<html lang="en">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>blah blah doc</title>
<style type="text/css">
...
...
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- lots of html tags p h1, h2 ul etc but no tables to be skipped over -->
<table id="something" summary="...">
<thead>
<th ...</th>
...
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>mark jones</td>

        <td>blah blah</td>
        <td>mark jones</td>
        <td>blah blah</td>
        <td>11/12/2009</td>
        <td>blah blah</td>

 </tr>
 ...
```

Would become:

```
...
<tr>
    <td>name1</td>

        <td>blah blah</td>
        <td>name1</td>
        <td>blah blah</td>
        <td>11/12/2009</td>
        <td>blah blah</td>

 </tr>
```

There is lots of other HTML tags and text before, after, and between the tables.

Above is just an example of a row; the name and other column data is different in each row. 
The whitespace is how it appears when I view source. I'm reasonably comfortable with Perl and Python, but don't know enough to tackle this.

Comment: I am curious to know what is the pattern of such data. If there is no regular pattern then how in the world are you going to figure out where the name <td> is ???  re: the name and other column data is different in each row.. pondering upon it !!!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that's it in a table and you have `lxml` installed (and the caveat that I haven't had my morning dose of coffee yet!):

```
html = """
<table>
<tr>
    <td>mark jones</td>

        <td>blah blah</td>
        <td>mark jones</td>
        <td>blah blah</td>
        <td>11/12/2009</td>
        <td>blah blah</td>

 </tr></table>"""

import lxml.html
import lxml.etree
from itertools import count


tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
next_name = lambda count=count(1): 'name{}'.format(next(count))
for trs in tree.findall('tr'):
    tds = trs.findall('td')
    anon_name = next_name()
    tds[0].text = anon_name
    tds[2].text = anon_name

print lxml.etree.tostring(tree)
```

Gives you:

```
<table><tr><td>name1</td>

        <td>blah blah</td>
        <td>name1</td>
        <td>blah blah</td>
        <td>11/12/2009</td>
        <td>blah blah</td>

 </tr></table>
```

Comment: +1 that it does work for the scenario posted, but how are you going to approach this problem if the guy says that the name and other data pattern is irregular ???

Comment: @Redian to put it simply - I won't :P (it's a completely different kettle of fish then...)

Comment: @Jon Clements This didn't work in my HTML file. I think the other HTML tags were throwing it off perhaps? Not sure how to get around that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @smithy then what is your HTML?

Comment: @Jon Clements - the HTML file is large and has company confidential info in, so I can't point to the actual file. However, I have updated the question to give more info on the HTML tags used. Thanks.

Comment: @Jon Clements - sorry, but I can't get it to work for my HTML file. I'm looking at for tr in enumerate(tree.cssselect('tr')):
 but haven't yet worked out how to get the tds for each tr it is returning...